# Using sum operation

Tags: sql

**This is my table**

```
Companyid   CompanyName Emp NAME    role    salary  bonus   others
     1         comp1    smith        ed      120    180     null
     1         comp1    raj       chairman   120    180     null
     1         comp1    ravi         sd      140    null    null
     1         comp1    guru         bd       40    null    40
     1         comp1    tech      director   null   null    null
     1         comp1    mahi       member    null   null    null
     1         comp1    sagi        ceo      null   null    null
```

i need output like this .sum of salary bonus ant others and whole sum of three columns

```
CompanyName Total Remunaration
comp1         820
```

Comment: Well, you've shown your source and desired result. What about your attempt to achieve this result? What have you tried? What went wrong in your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this query:

```
SELECT CompanyName, SUM(COALESCE(salary, 0) + COALESCE(bonus, 0) + COALESCE(others, 0)) AS TotalRemunaration
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CompanyName
```

I use `COALESCE(fieldName, 0)` that will return 0 when value of fieldName is Null.